# Getting this error: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=Infinity), but I have Container( height: 88, width: 375,

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Getting Error on line with "child: Row(" at the end of this code snippet, seems like I should not get it since the Container has height=88, width=375, thoughts?

```
        Container(
          height: 88,
          width: 375,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                bottom: -1,
                child: Text(
                  " ",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: AppColors.primaryText,
                    fontFamily: "HK Grotesk",
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontSize: 24,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: -1,
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/logo.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.none,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 17,
                right: 24,
                bottom: 2,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
```

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: see title: Getting this error: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=Infinity)

Comment: debugging some, if I add height: 88, right above the Row( then the error goes away.  Should not have to do this since the Container() Row() is in has height: 88.